# TFS (vNext) + Karma + Chrome : Chrome have not captured in 60000 ms, killing

Tags: google-chrome, tfs, build, karma-runner, tfsbuild

[image][image]

I am trying to build our team's UI through TFS 2015(vNext) on premises builds.
I am using Grunt build step in vNext to call a gruntjs file which will build all the grunt tasks.

Currently,the build is failing because of the task is not able to Start chrome and is timing out "Chrome have not captured in 60000 ms, killing." **I see it is able to start chrome for some grunt tasks but fails for some.** **When I run the grunt command directly calling the gruntjs file from cmdline or powershell console on the build server, it works perfectly fine but it fails from the vNext builds.**

I rolled back the chrome version to "51.0.2704.103 m" from "52.0.2743.116 m" and tried but still no success.

I went through the links which discuss the same issue. But I am not sure if this is a chrome issue as it works for some grunt tasks.

I am stuck with this since past week and on the verge of giving up, any help will be really great.

Thanks

**ERROR**

```
[32m31 08 2016 11:27:53.800:INFO [karma]: [39mKarma v0.13.22 server started at http://localhost:8888/
[32m31 08 2016 11:27:53.815:INFO [launcher]: [39mStarting browser Chrome
[33m31 08 2016 11:28:49.663:WARN [launcher]: [39mChrome have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
[32m31 08 2016 11:28:49.757:INFO [launcher]: [39mTrying to start Chrome again (1/2).
[33m31 08 2016 11:28:53.834:WARN [launcher]: [39mChrome have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
[32m31 08 2016 11:28:53.912:INFO [launcher]: [39mTrying to start Chrome again (1/2).
[33m31 08 2016 11:29:49.779:WARN [launcher]: [39mChrome have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
[32m31 08 2016 11:29:49.842:INFO [launcher]: [39mTrying to start Chrome again (2/2).
[33m31 08 2016 11:29:53.931:WARN [launcher]: [39mChrome have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
[32m31 08 2016 11:29:53.993:INFO [launcher]: [39mTrying to start Chrome again (2/2).
[33m31 08 2016 11:30:49.852:WARN [launcher]: [39mChrome have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
[31m31 08 2016 11:30:49.930:ERROR [launcher]: [39mChrome failed 2 times (timeout). Giving up.
[33mWarning: Task "karma:ci" failed. Use --force to continue.[39m
[31mAborted due to warnings.[39m
    [33mWarning:  Use --force to continue.[39m

    [31mAborted due to warnings.[39m
Grunt failed with error: C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\npm\grunt.cmd failed with return code: 6
```

Comment: Are you using the latest edition Update3 of TFS 2015? Share a screenshot of your build definition and your task setting on how to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Did you configure your build agent to run in interactive mode?

Comment: @Cece-MSFT -- I have added the screenshot to the original question..Before the UI build I am getting the packages with npm install...

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT -- Agent is configured to run as a service

Comment: Can you configure it to run in interactive mode and then try again?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT .. I ran the agent in the interactive mode , I still face the same issue..any help will be great..

Comment: @Cece-MSFT we are using on premsies Update 2- TFS 2015..We are scheduled to upgrade it in next few weeks..

Answer (score 3):

this worked for me:

1) install puppeteer

```
npm install puppeteer --save-dev
```

2) add this code to karma conf at the very top of your module exports function:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
process.env.CHROME_BIN = puppeteer.executablePath();
```

3) disable chrome sandbox:

```
browsers: ['ChromeNoSandbox'],
customLaunchers: {
    ChromeNoSandbox: {
        base: 'Chrome',
        flags: ['--no-sandbox']
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce your issue and fixed it by launching Chrome with "nosandbox".

Use following configuration in your karma project.conf.js:

```
browsers: ['ChromeNoSandbox'],
    customLaunchers: {
        ChromeNoSandbox: {
            base: 'Chrome',
            flags: ['--no-sandbox']
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Eddie, I did try the above fix but I still face the same issue.. I tried it in interactive mode as well..When i run it in interactive mode google chrome opens up and runs in an unresponsive manner.. So, to troubleshoot i created a vNext build definition that just runs a powershell task to open chrome-start-process "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"..it opens in an an unresponsive mode but it works from powershell console in the server. I have attached a pic of chrome in the original post..i tried older versions of chrome as well but still the same issue..